# How to change a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to change a variable depending on what it's current value is:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {     
    if (direction === leftnav){
        direction = rightnav
    }
    else{
       direction = leftnav
    };

    loadPage(location.pathname);
});
```

this doesn't seem to work somehow :s
can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: here is the full  js file: http://pastebin.com/7zZseW74

EDIT 2: what seems to happen is that the loadPage function just does not seem to fire...

Comment: What "does not work"? What is the value of `direction`, `leftnav` and `rightnav`? Your example is too vague to be answerable...

Comment: basicaly, i add css differenly depending on the value of direction.

Now i want to intercept a popstate event but invert the direction, so change the variable set earlier.

Comment: What are `direction`, `leftnav`, and `rightnav`?

Comment: @Šime direction cathes the class of a parent element. If the class is leftnav it sets it to leftnav, if it is not it sets it to another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `==` instead of `===`:

```
if (direction == leftnav) {
   direction = rightnav;
} else {
   direction = leftnav;
}
```

Also, do include proper `;` inside `if` and `else` clauses. You could also provide more information in order to get better help. Information like: what are `leftnav` and `rightnav` variables. If they are not variables but literals, you should enclose them within `"`. Like `"rightnav"` and `"leftnav"`.

Comment: Actually, last `;` is perfectly fine, it should be there. It's for `window.addEventListener`. Additionally, in Javascript you can have multiple `;` without any problem (and missing ones for that matter; those are added automatically).

Comment: @Olli: Agree. But question was edited. I didn't have that information when I wrote the answer. :-)

Comment: I think he meant the one after if, not the very last one.

Comment: @pablo I tried both, it didn't work :(. I've included the full file in the main post now

Comment: Oh well, true. Still, little known fact, line breaks are enough, you don't have to use ;, and you can add additional ;'s without problem.

Comment: @Pablo Why `==` instead of `===`? If the issue is with the operands being of different types (for instance one being Number and the other being String), then an explicit cast would be proper (like: `direction === +leftnav`). Using `==` just to make it work is not a good idea, imho.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (direction == leftnav){
```

^ requires only 2 '=' signs.

should be correct for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you're missing is semicolons.

```
if (direction == leftnav) {
    direction = rightnav;
} else {
    direction = leftnav;
}
```

Also, unnecessary ===

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (direction == 'leftnav')
    {direction = 'rightnav';}
else
    {direction = 'leftnav';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said a thing about leftnav and rightnav variable, so I suspect that you may want to use strings ('leftnav' and 'rightnav') instead, otherwise both are likely to be undefineds.

EDIT: Now that you posted the code, brief look at it suggests that yes, you wanted quoted strings.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    direction = (direction=="leftnav")?"rightnav":"leftnav";
    loadPage(location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: SnippetSpace, I couldn't find definitions. And I still can't.

Comment: direction = $(this).attr('class');

That happens before a popstate in any case

Comment: I was talking about leftnav and rightnav, not direction. Now that you say that loadPage() doesn't seem to fire, it's totoally different issue, I guess your event listener doesn't fire at all then. Tried putting debug something in there?

Comment: the event does load when i remove the if else statements. And i see what you mean now, leftnav and rightnav are the variable values so i should add quotes around it i guess.